# Cannot execute query using adodb

Tags: php, adodb-php

I am getting a weird issue when I try to execute a query in adodb5. 
I am trying to get data from a mssql server. The echo "Connection established.
" is printed. But everything stopped working after executing query. I have put an echo after an nothing is shown. Nothing is shown in phperrors log file.
Thanks in advance.

```
if( $db ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
    $result = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM T_MODIFIKIMARTIKULLI");

    if ($result === false) { 
        die("failed");
    }

    while (!$result->EOF) {
        for ($i=0, $max=$result->FieldCount(); $i < $max; $i++) {
            print $result->fields[$i].' ';
        }
        $result->MoveNext();
        print "<br>\n";
    } 
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
}
```

Comment: Michel, your edit do not work. it stops at $result = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM T_MODIFIKIMARTIKULLI");

Comment: I edited the code to fix the indentation for clarity and added braces `{}` on the `if` and `for` one liners to add clarity to your question. It was never intended to make it work. Look at the revision side by side to see it does the code.

Comment: what is the result of `if (!$result) { print $db->ErrorMsg();}` . put this between  the `Execute` and before `if($result === false)...`. Maybe that will tell you what error is encountered.

Comment: Thank you for replying back. I used successfully another way and it worked. Adodb has problems for me at least